# Location manager do not detect beacons

Tags: swift, ios8, ibeacon

I have an `iPod` and 2 `iBeacons` as it is on the image below:

[image]

Within `AppDelegate`
 I have 2 properties:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let myRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, identifier: "myRegion")
```

Inside `application:didFinishLauncingWithOptions` I set my locationManager delegate:

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(myRegion)
locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(myRegion)
locationManager.requestStateForRegion(myRegion)
```

Method of that delegate:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    print("--->>>\(beacons.count)")
}
```

always prints `--->>>0`. Why? Since there are 2 iBeacons? What am I doing wrong?

I think it is not working because sth is wrong with my region? Do you know how to get uuid for **my own** beacons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ranging for beacons with UUID `"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"` which is the default UUID of *Estimote* beacons. The picture you posted shows *Kontakt.io* beacons.

[This page](http://fosbury.vervemobile.com/beacon-comparison/kontakt) claims that the default UUID of *Kontakt* beacons is `"F7826DA6-4FA2-4E98-8024-BC5B71E0893E."`

Most beacon vendors also provide their own beacon management apps which enable you to discover (and change) UUID's of your own beacons—I'd look for one in the App Store.